# SQL Server Alert Based On Severity Level Not Working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to SQL Server alerts, and I am trying to setup an alert That will run a job and send a notification, based on severity level.

In order to test if the alert works correctly I have downloaded a sample corrupted database from [MSDN Blogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20150913193654/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2007/04/17/example-corrupt-database-to-play-with.aspx), and I have restored the database and issued a query against the database which failed with error 824 and level 24.

But although the error is a severe error and was logged to both the SQL log and the Windows Application Log nothing seemed to work, I have even tested with both an alert on the specific database and on all databases. (I have even setup alerts on all other levels from 19 and above just to confirm that nothing is happening.)

However an alert based on error number 824 did work, as well as an alert based on the performance counter's Sql Error counter did worked correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Agent may need to be restarted to pick up the configuration changes.

Comment: Interesting that all other alerts did worked, it might be just that sometimes we have to restart services in order for them to function properly

Comment: Interesting I had now again the same thing in that I have added two alerts one for the specific database and another for all database, and the alert for all databases worked but not the alert for the specific database until I restarted SQL agent after which it worked properly

Comment: I have never heard of having to restart the Agent service every time a configuration change is made. Are you sure this is the right fix for your problem? This was issues in SQL 2005 in some instances of using alert type: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926612

Comment: This turned out to solve the problem, and as such for every change to alerts that I am doing I make sure to restart it as I am not looking for trouble

Comment: @Shawn it is most probably a bug and it would have to be reported to Microsoft, however the feedback button on SQL Server's connect page takes me nowhere, this is besides that I don't believe that they will be able to repro it

Comment: What build number is your instance running at? Are you at the latest SP and CU for SQL 2008 R2?

Comment: @Shawn It's Service Pack 1, but even that should not have the problem it just does